# How to get URL path in C# .Net from the HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, url

I want to get the all the path of URL except the current page of url, eg: my URL is http://www.MyIpAddress.com/red/green/default.aspx I want to get "http://www.MyIpAddress.com/red/green/" only. How can I get.I'm doing like

```
string sPath = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri).OriginalString; System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
            sPath = sPath.Replace("http://", "");
            System.IO.FileInfo oInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(sPath);
            string sRet = oInfo.Name;
            Response.Write(sPath.Replace(sRet, ""));
```

Its showing exception on new System.IO.FileInfo(sPath) as sPath contain "localhost/red/green/default.aspx" saying  "The given path's format is not supported."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't treat it as a URI problem, treat it a string problem. Then it's nice and easy.

```
String originalPath = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri).OriginalString;
String parentDirectory = originalPath.Substring(0, originalPath.LastIndexOf("/"));
```

Really is that easy!

Edited to add missing parenthesis.

Comment: This is dangerous, Shibu Thomas' [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35194130/1107768) is better. Consider for example the situation when the URL would contain a '/' in the query string or fragment.

Comment: What's the difference between new Uri(...).OriginalString vs ...AsboluteUri.ToString() ?

Comment: Does not cater for all URIs...  you are assuming there will be a / in the string but a valid URI could just have querystrings towards the end...

Answer (score 105):

Main URL : http://localhost:8080/mysite/page.aspx?p1=1&p2=2

**Get different parts of URL in C#.**

```
Value of HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
localhost

Value of HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority
localhost:8080

Value of HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
/mysite/page.aspx

Value of HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath
/mysite

Value of HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
http://localhost:8080/mysite/page.aspx?p1=1&p2=2

Value of HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl
/mysite/page.aspx?p1=1&p2=2

Value of HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery
/mysite/page.aspx?p1=1&p2=2
```

Comment: And if you are dealing with a Url not in the current request, just `new Uri(myUrlString);` then leverage these properties.

Comment: No. This is a **misleading** answer, as it doesn't relate to the context of the question, specifically relating to any URL, not just the current Request Url available in an ASP.NET web application.

Answer (score 3):

**Replace this :**

```
            string sRet = oInfo.Name;
            Response.Write(sPath.Replace(sRet, ""));
```

**With following:**

```
        string sRet = oInfo.Name;           
        int lastindex = sRet.LastIndexOf("/");
        sRet=sRet.Substring(0,lastindex)
        Response.Write(sPath.Replace(sRet, ""));
```

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
string sPath = (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url).ToString();
sPath = sPath.Replace("http://", "");
var oInfo = new  System.IO.FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
string sRet = oInfo.Name;
Response.Write(sPath.Replace(sRet, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

This may get you want you want if you're just trying to navigate to another page on your site, but it doesn't get the absolute path if you really need that.  You can navigate within the site without using the absolute path.

```
string loc = "";
loc = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath + "/NewDestinationPage.aspx";
Response.Redirect(loc, true);
```

If you really need the absolute path, you can pick off the parts and build what you need with the Uri class:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
myUri.Scheme
myUri.Host  // or DnsSafeHost
myUri.Port
myUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)  // etc.
```

[Good article](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths) on the subject of ASP.NET paths.