# jump from character and remove string after that

Tags: c#

I want to delete a part of the text but I do not know how to do it.

this is my address : `https://localhost:44390/upload/productpic/productmainpic`

i need to remove this in my address : `https://localhost:44390/` it should be like this : `upload/productpic/productmainpic`

i find first index of 'h' with this line but when i need to find '/' of `upload` it find `/` of `https://` .

**now how can i do this work ???**

Comment: you should post your code buddy, we can't really see what is going wrong in your logic if you don't post it

Comment: So you want to keep only the part of the url without the domain. You could use regex for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this the System.Uri class like this:

```
System.Uri uri = new Uri("https://localhost:44390/upload/productpic/productmainpic");
string uriWithoutScheme = uri.PathAndQuery + uri.Fragment;
```

This wil give you /upload/productpic/productmainpic

Comment: In addition: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35194130/5453249) answer for how to get different parts of an uri